# CupertinoPicker infinite scroll instead empty space

Tags: flutter

I have a cupertino picker, however when I enter the view I can see a lot of empty space at the top. How can I make an infinite scroll there, or remove the empty space?

[image]

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      child: CupertinoPicker(
          scrollController: scrollController,
          itemExtent: 64.0,
          selectionOverlay: Container(),
          onSelectedItemChanged: (value) => widget.callback(widget.data[value]),
          children: widget.data
              .map(
                (e) => Center(child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
                    ),
                    child: Text(e))),
          )
              .toList()),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your parent container height and/or set your initialItem to something other than the default 0.

```
scrollController = FixedExtentItemScrollController(initialItem: 3);
```

Comment: I done that already, but still I dont want the empty space at the top and bottom. Is there way to get rid of that completely?

Comment: Edited answer.   You can also change the diameterRatio once that is tighter.  I haven't tried setting the height to less than your itemExtent, I would assume that would error, but maybe not.